# C++ Stl Vector insert empty(NULL) node

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Because of my algorithm i have to insert some empty(NULL) nodes into my vector,some gaps i mean.How can i perform this?

I had tried like

```
array.push_back(NULL);
```

But it adds nodes with 0 value.

Edit:

I get values from integer array like int a[10000] and insert them into vector sirali_dizi with leaving some gaps into my vector.So i want to leave some gaps but with this every round i want to sort my array also.So i can't use -1 or 0 etc.

Comment: It's an array which have values to sort.

Comment: Exact types are important in C++. Please add the declaration of array into you question.

Comment: It sounds like `std::vector` is the _wrong_ data structure for your scenario.

Comment: So which data structure is suitable for my situation?

Comment: @droidmachine: We still don't know why you need these gaps, what you mean by every round, etc, etc. Without seeing the *actual* code or a much more concise statement of the *actual* problem you are trying to solve the best we can do is guess.

Comment: Because i want to implement this sorting algorithm.So i have to leave some gaps in my array.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_sort

Comment: @droidmachine: Ah well I would've started with that. Actually at this point I'd scrap this question. Ask a new question "How do I implement a library sort algorithm using STL containers?" and in that question post the code you have so far, link this wiki article for reference, and briefly describe where you got stuck.

Comment: i asked this question before but they said me "hire a coder for this " :)

Comment: @droidmachine: I'd hazard a guess that was probably because you failed to include your code or were overly vague. The devil is in the details and programmers often get perturbed if they don't have enough of them to solve the problem. FWIW you probably want to use `std::list` ...

Answer (score -6, accepted):

You could make a vector of pointers to int instead of int:

```
vector<int*> vInt;
vInt.push_back(NULL);
```

And then access the values this way:

```
vector<int*>::iterator iIter;
for(iIter = vInt.begin(); iIter != vInt.end(); iIter++){
    if(*iIter != NULL){
        // Notice the double asterisk: it's a pointer (the iterator) to another pointer (the value)
        cout << **iIter << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: So if i do vInt.push_back(21); it's not an adress 21 is a value?

Comment: No, 21 would be an address. You would have to do this vInt.push_back(new int(21)); Remember to free the memory when you're done using it.

Comment: -1: I wouldn't accept an answer with invalid syntax that advocates this kind of dereference. @droidmachine you need to clarify your question and show a more complete code example to get better answers.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. It introduces all sorts of memory management issues.

Comment: I want to implement Library Sort so i have to leave some gaps in my vector.

Comment: array.insert(array.begin()+groupsize+20,NULL); give some errors for vector<int *> array.How can i fix this?

Comment: @droidmachine You could start by telling us what error you get.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `NULL` is `#define`d to be 0.

If your vector is a collection of pointers, then `NULL` (0) is always an illegal pointer value, and can safely be checked against without worrying about false positives.

If your array is of integers where 0 is allowed, then you'll have to use some other sentinel value to differentiate. `NULL` is intended to be used with pointers.

Comment: like if you put -1 to a array that you know that will just have positive integers.

Comment: But my vector have values to sort.So i can't use a value like -1.If i use pointers can i use values in this vector ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not mandatory to use `NULL` to detect empty nodes.
You can use `NULL` if you don't use the value '0' or use some other value for example, -1, `INF` etc to note empty nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't say much about your algorithm. I guess Boost optional maybe helpful.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

There is one extra state. You can modify your sort algorithm  to check if(value) exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you have NULL values you need a type that can encapsulate this information.
Here a note can be invalid or valid (with a value).

```
class Node
{
    bool   valid;
    int    value;

    public:
    Node(int v): valid(true), value(v) {}
    Node():      valid(false)          {}

    bool isValid() const {return valid;}

    Node& operator=(int newValue)
    {
        valid = true;
        value = newValue;
        return *this;
    }
    void makeInvalid()
    {
        valid = false;
    }
    bool operator<(Node const& rhs) const
    {
        // If both are invalid then neither is less.
        // If one is invalid the invalid one is less
        // Otherwise use the value to sort by

        if (!valid && !rhs.value)      { return false;}
        if ( valid && !rhs.valid)      { return false;}
        if (!valid &&  rhs.valid)      { return true;}
        return value < rhs.valid;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, Node const& value)
    {
       if (value.isValid())
       {    stream << value.value;
       }
       else
       {    stream << "-- NULL --";
       }
       return stream;
    }
};
```

Then you can use this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<Node>   data;

    data.push_back(1);
    data.push_back(2);
    data.push_back(Node()); // Invalid or NULL value.

    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<Node>(std::cout, " ")
             );
}
```

Then running you get:

```
> g++ sort.cpp
> ./a.out
-- NULL -- 1 2
```